# Windows Universal App SetTitleBar

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a question about the Title'Bar sample from Microsoft's GitHub repository(https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/FullScreenTitleBarRepo/tree/master/FullScreenTitleBarRepo): In the AddCustomTitleBar function,there has a line:

```
customTitleBar.EnableControlsInTitleBar(areControlsInTitleBar);
```

EnableControlsInTitleBar is here:

```
public void EnableControlsInTitleBar(bool enable)
{
    if (enable)
    {
        TitleBarControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        // Clicks on the BackgroundElement will be treated as clicks on the title bar.
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(BackgroundElement);
    }
    else
    {
        TitleBarControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(null);
    }
}
```

but if I don't call the fuction(EnableControlsInTitleBar),the sample still work well

In Justin XL sample(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar) there indeed have use this:

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(BackgroundElement);
```

that puzzled me,hope somebody can give me a explain，thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "but if I don't call the fuction(EnableControlsInTitleBar),the sample
>   still work well"

I don't think it's the truth. There are several places will call this function, so I think you didn't comment out all of them.

The following line is used to let your custom title bar can handle input(for example the mouse click) like default title bar.

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(BackgroundElement);
```

Take the MS sample as example here. If we launch the MS sample without any change, you can do the following actions:

Select "***2) Custom drawing***" -> check "Extend view into title bar" -> check "Enable controls in title bar" -> you will see the following title bar and be able to check the checkbox on title bar.[image]

But if we comment out the SetTitleBar call, the checkbox will not response to your mouse click.