# Change a Windows Store App's title text

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

How can I change the shown title of the app? (Like **Photos** does)

In Winforms that would be `form1.Text = "new title";`.

How do we do that in UWP?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

...

ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
appView.Title = "Title text goes here";
```

Comment: Anything that solves [the issue @Parham.D sees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37260436/1028230), namely that the text has the title appended? If I want to set it programmatically, but without the *- AppName* appended, what would I do?

Comment: I guess there's [this sort of complete customization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32648955/1028230) ([another example](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/), both pretty much copies of [this from Microsoft on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar)), but that's a little overkill-ish imo. Guess I'll just deal with the app name in the "wrong" order for now. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, GetForCurrentView gives : System.Exception: 'Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)'

Answer (score 14):

When I use `ApplicationView`, it appends the `Title` to the assembly name.

We could edit `Application` -> `Display Name`  in the `Package.appxmanifest` file.

Comment: In addition to setting the name in the `Package.appxmanifest`, it is also necessary to check the box for the different logo sizes that you want to display the app title.